# Azure DevOps Permissions - Remove permission to create new work items on Boards

Tags: azure-devops, permissions

I would like to control the users who can create new Work Items on my board. So that some user won't have this permission.
But I would like that these users should be able to move created Work Items throw the board ("approved" to "in progress", etc).
I want to remove the specific permission to add new Work Items.

Is that possible? And if it is possible. How can I do it? Didn't find it on any documentation.

I only found this permission where I can set if the user can edit Work Items. Removing it, the user can't create new work items, but it can't move working items too :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a project group for such restrictions and edit your process on the org level to add a new rule. Check this:

1. [Get started with permissions, access, and security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)
2. [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops)
3. [Restrict creation of work items by a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-samples?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance#restrict-creation-of-work-items-by-a-group)

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you! I haven't look for organization permissions before! It worked like a charm! Thank you again Shamrai Aleksander :)